# Clean URLs disabled even though module-rewrite is on

Tags: uri

I have a manually installed LAMP environment on Ubuntu 15.10 **Desktop** and when I came to install Drupal 8 on it i've seen that clean URLs are disabled, so I turned on the Apache2 (2.4.12) rewrite module in the terminal via:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Than I got:

```
Module rewrite already enabled
```

And yet when I cleared the browsers' cache and refreshed the installation page I still get:

> Clean URLs Disabled.
>
> Your server is capable of using clean URLs, but it is not enabled. Using clean URLs gives an improved user experience and is recommended.

So, if I turned on the rewrite module, why Drupal 8 still can't use them?

Comment: I think most of these questions are flagged as off-topic. In order to diagnose the issue, you should provide the Apache version as this makes a difference.

Comment: Updated the version.

Comment: Sometimes the test fails, while it shouldn't. You can try to force them om and see what happens: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121958/how-i-can-force-enable-clean-url-d7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same problem, I opened the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and located this portion of the file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And found that AllowOverride is set to None. Go ahead and replace it with All.

Restart your apache service when done.

Comment: Hi Shabir! From some reason this file is empty when I open it with Geany ... Is there another file maybe ?

Comment: Have you tried cd /etc/apache2 and ls the files

Comment: I edited the code, the file name is apache2.conf

Comment: Shabir, it worked for me only when I changed the rest of the AllowOverride directives to All, and not only that one (btw, at your document there seems to be Require all granted by nature... At me at was "Require all denied" but I changed it also to granted... Anyways, now it seems to work fine and the notification no longer appear in the setup.