# Due to Clean Url issue, the site is not working

Tags: 8, uri

I have downloaded Drupal 8 from official site.But during installation it shows following error:
[image]

but i continue installation, and it installed properly. The problem is that except home page whenever i click on any link it shows "Page Not Found".

I have enabled mod_rewrite for apache . Also i uncomment and edit "RewriteBase/d8" in.htaccess file.

I tried all whatever i found on drupal.org but nothing work for me.I desperate to work in d8 but helpless to continue.
Million of Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled mod_rewrite for Apache, and restarted Apache. Then I simply commented out the `RewriteBase /` part of the .htaccess file on line 110. Apart from this, I didn't change anything in Apache configuration files. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I opened the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and located this portion of the file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And found that AllowOverride is set to None. Go ahead and replace it with All.

Restart your apache service when done. Similar question is asked [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185262/clean-urls-disabled-even-though-module-rewrite-is-on/185263#185263)