# Mod rewrite enabled and working, urls contain index.php/

Tags: 8, uri

I have a strange issue: I have a drupal 8 instance on a subfolder in `/var/www`, I have enabled mod-rewrite in apache, I changed the `apache.config` file as in [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185262/clean-urls-disabled-even-though-module-rewrite-is-on) post and the clean urls are working if I navigate directly to `/drupal/admin` for example.

I also added the `RewriteBase /drupal` in my .htaccess file.

The problem is that any link generated by drupal still contains the `/drupal/index.php/` part and I don't know how to get rid of that `/index.php` part.

I worked with Drupal 7 since it was launched but I never had this problem.

Is there a setting somewhere in db or in the config file where I should 'tell' drupal to use clean urls?

My server runs Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't append /index.php to the base URL (e.g. setting `$base_url` to http://example.com/index.php, in the settings.php file), then the rewrite rules in the Apache configuration files are wrongly adding /index.php to your links.
Check both of them, and you should find what is causing the wrong behavior.

Comment: Hi i have the same problem and checked the settings.php file there is nothing which sets base_url path. So maybe its a problem of my host? I wonder because some links are standard without the "index.php" and some are with. How is this possible?

Comment: To me the clean URLs which are autodetected in drupal 8 in every request as seen [here]: https://www.drupal.org/node/1659580 gave me the same impression ...

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same or similar problem with Drupal 10.1.x when logged in when running PHP (8.1.x) as a FPM application on Apache 2.2. i.e. index.php being prepended to url path despite mod_rewrite being enabled. For me I was able to modify the .htaccess file and then after restarting the web service and clearing drupal cache, sometimes twice, with the following changed in my .htaccess.

```
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
+ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!=/favicon.ico"
```

I have posted an issue here for this.

https://talk.plesk.com/threads/index-php-prepended-to-drupal-10-1-x-admin-paths-when-running-php-as-fpm-application-served-via-apache.372187/