# Links on site adding index.php in URL

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a Drupal 8 site and am encountering an issue. When I visit the site as an anonymous user and click a link on the menu, it adds /index.php to the url. Then if I navigate to that page and click another link in adds another index.php (i.e. example.com/index.php/index.php/link1/link2) and therefore the page will not load. This does not happen if I am logged into the site, has anyone encountered this before? I tried a fresh htaccess file and beyond that I am stumped. It is on a shared hosting plan. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200596/mod-rewrite-enabled-and-working-urls-contain-index-php

Comment: Thank you, I did see that question, but there was not a definitive answer that I could find.

Comment: Have you found a solution to the /index.php/index.php/ problem? I'm afraid this has something to do with Views…

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

I have a view with links to content, where the URLs are *item/[one content's field value]*. One day, I watched the view as anonymous user and noticed that these had been changed to *index.php/index.php/item/[one content's field value]*. (On the other hand, when I visited as administrator user, it didn't happen.)

I didn't know why it happened, and it was solved by executing `drush cc render`.

However, the problem would still be left.

The environment is Drupal 8.3.9 and PHP 7.0.25.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-05-22/indexphp-in-urls-randomly#comment-13131756):

> A solution. Install the [Redirect Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect), the default setting of
> Enforce clean and canonical URLs will fix the issue. However, there is
> also a long outstanding bug Route normalizer: Global Redirect in
> Drupal which apparently is the cause, but hasn't been pushed to Core
> yet.

Comment: Redirect fixed it for me (Drupal 9.3.6 Apache 2.4.29 PHP 7.4.28) after index.php was incorrectly inserted in links to uploaded files after many years of not being a problem. So I'd say there's quite likely a bug in core still?